# as3 arguments and inheritance

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, inheritance

In a flex project, I have created kind of abstract class named `AbstractAlert` and some subclass of `AbstractAlert` named `Alert1`, `Alert2`...

I manipulate `Vector` of type `Alert1`, `Alert2`...like this :

```
var alerts1:Vector.<Alert1> = new Vector.<Alert1>();
var alerts2:Vector.<Alert2> = new Vector.<Alert2>();
```

How can I han handle generic function to manipulate these vectors ?

I can't call this function :

```
private function someFunction(from:Vector.<AbstractAlerte>):void
{
...
}

someFunction(alerts1);
```

Is there a way to make generic function ?

Comment: It was simple... someFunction(Vector.<AbstractAlerte>(alerts1));  Solved

Comment: notice that due to the cast, we don't have the same reference of `Vector` inside and outside function thus in my function I can only read/consult entries of my `Vector`. If I try to modify `from` variable, original `Vector` (ie: alerts1) is not modify, but `from` is.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This section isn't correct

Concerning your second comment, yes, you won't modify the original object if it is an Vector (iirc? Same goes for Array as well, i think). This isn't because of the cast, but because passed arguments of Array and Vector types are not treated a references.

If you want to modify the passed Vector, you could do the following:

```
var alerts1:Vector<Alert1> = new Vector.<Alert1>();
...fill with objects
alerts1[0].property = "hey";
trace(alerts1[0].property); //output : "hey"
alerts1 = Vector.<Alert1>(someFunction(Vector.<AbstractAlerte>(alerts1)));
trace(alerts1[0].property); //output : "sup"

private function someFunction(from:Vector.<AbstractAlerte>):Vector.<AbstractAlerte>
{
    from[0].property = "sup";
    return from;
}
```

---

But this seems a bit cumbersome, don't you think? With an Interface that all Alert Classes implement, you could forego all this casting back and forth.

Lets say you have an Interface called IAlert. Instead of writing

`var alerts1:Vector<Alert1> = new Vector.<Alert1>();`

you could write

`var alerts1:Vector<IAlert> = new Vector.<IAlert>();`

and fill it with Objects of type Alert1. Give IAlert a function called

`public function get type():String`

Include a variable to hold the type of the class in AbstractAlert, and set the type in the constructors of Alert1 and Alert2, like this in essence:

```
public interface IAlert{
    function get type():String;
}

public class AbstractAlert implements IAlert{
    private var _type:String;

    public function AbstractAlert(type:String){
        this._type = type;
    }

    public function get type():String{return "AbstractAlert";}
}

public class Alert1 extends AbstractAlert implements IAlert{
    public function Alert1(){
        super("Alert1");
    }

    public function get type():String {return super.type;}
}
```

then, finally in your `someFunction` function:

```
private function someFunction(from:Vector.<IAlert>):Vector.<IAlert>{
    if(from{0].type == "Alert1"){
       //do stuff with Alert1 classes
    }
    etc.

    return from;
}
```

This is untested code, but I hope you get the gist of what I'm saying.

Comment: Very nice explaination, I will test tomorrow some code snippet. Thank you +1 for sure

Answer (score 0):

DodgerThud, I'm pretty sure that your assertion :

> This isn't because of the cast, but because passed arguments of Array and Vector types are not treated a references

is false because I tested this code :

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var _vector:Vector.<Alert1> = new Vector.<Alert1>();            

        protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // Alert1 is extending AbstractAlert
            _vector.push(new Alert1());
            _vector.push(new Alert1());

            trace(_vector.length);
            modify(Vector.<AbstractAlert>(_vector));
            trace(_vector.length);
            modify2(_vector);
            trace(_vector.length);

        }

        protected function modify(vector:Vector.<AbstractAlert>):void
        {
            vector.splice(0, 1);
        }

        protected function modify2(vector:Vector.<Alert1>):void
        {
            vector.splice(0, 1);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

And result is :

> 2
>   2
>   1

So we can pass vectors by reference (I believe that only primitives types are passed by values).

Comment: Interesting, looks like I got mixed up with something else. But at least now everything seem to be working for you correctly, yes? You can remove your vote from my answer if you want to, I'll edit down to only the Interface section.

Comment: For now, it's not really solved as I have created 3 functions (for my 3 subclasses) and duplicate code because I want to operate on my vectors (delete/add operations). I will test something with interfaces later when I will have more time to do